# Reduce My for loop complexity to 4 as per sonar confiuration

Tags: java, sonarqube

I integrated code to sonarqube for quality code and set method complexity is 4.
Please help me to reduce this for loop complexity to 4

```
for (int i = 1; i <= retryCount + count; i++) {
    try {
        if (cat!= null)
            grps = cat.getAllGroups(category);
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (i >= retryCount + count) {
            throw new MyException(new Fault(1009,
                        new Object[] { e.getMessage() }));
        } else {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("No Records Found")) {
                break;
            } else {
                String status = handleIOAutomationException(ctx, e);
                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
                    throw new MyException(new Fault(1009,
                                new Object[] { e.getMessage() }));
                } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("some")) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract your logic into its own sub methods and try make these shorter. You should also try to make your identifiers more readable.

```
public void method() {
    ...
    int maxLoops = retryCount + count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLoops; i++) {
        if (tryToGetAllGroups(maxLoops, i))
            break;
    }
}

private boolean tryToGetAllGroups(int maxLoops, int i) throws MyException {
    try {
        if (cat != null)
            grps = cat.getAllGroups(category);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) { // you should make Exception more specific!
        if (i >= maxLoops) {
            return throwFinalException(e);
        } else {
            if (tryToGetCat(e)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean tryToGetCat(Exception e) throws MyException {
    if (e.getMessage().contains("No Records Found")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        String status = handleIOAutomationException(ctx, e);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
            throwFinalException(e);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("some")) {
            // try to get cat here
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean throwFinalException(Exception e) throws MyException {
    throw new MyException(new Fault(1009,
            new Object[]{e.getMessage()}));
}
```

Comment: If we return Boolean flag what about my result data

Comment: You don't have any in your code. But you can also return your result and check for result != null.